# Ionic 2 / Laravel 5.2 communication with the API

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Im a mega newbie at Ionic 2 and Angular 2, but i have quite a bit of background in PHP.

I have built my API in Laravel 5.2, at the moment, i have a login URL as follows:

```
http://www.website.com/api/v1/login
```

Which obviously returns a token if login is successful.

I have also built a form in ionic 2 using CSS and HTML, which is in the default /app/pages/home/home.html

What i want to do is make the login form actual communicate with the API but i cant find any examples on how to do this in Ionic v2.0.0-beta.32

All i want to do is redirect to a blank page if successful or display an alert if it fails.

I would love if someone could give me a bit of a helping hand.

Respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you mean with "make the login form actual communicate with the API".

If you mean the actual http communication you'd need to understand `$http` and `Observables`. If you search for those terms you will find plenty of information and examples.

If that is not what you mean please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your response ... What i mean by that, is when the user enters their email and password, i want it to call the Laravel API i have written, run the functions, return the jSON and if they are legit, go to a dummy page, if not then bring up an alert or something ... I have found a few tuts, but none of them work with Ionic 2

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a similar solution connection laravel to ionic 2.
From what I've learned, after you connect to laravel, you'll get the token, and this token will be used in all the requests to laravel/api.
Check for jwt-auth and satelizer for the angular authentication.
Some links that may help:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/ionic

The first one is to prepare the laravel part, the second for the ionic.

NOTE:: In the first link, I faced some issues and problems, not with the code, but with the reference links.

Ex:

`'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuthFacades\JWTFactory::class`

should be

`'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class`

It's missing some backslashes.